# SVN server with reporitory in network folder

Tags: svn, configuration, network-share, collabnet

I want to configure SVN server in windows with the network repository path. When I changed the SVN parent path to a network path it does not work.

I have Collabnet SVN server running in **Machine1** and I want to configure the following networkpath as parent repository path,
SVN parent path: \Machine2\test\repos\

Windows authentication is required for the **Machine2**, but I dont know how to configure above and it fails currently.

Any pointers/suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might mount the network folder to a drive letter, saving the credentials.

Can you clarify why you want to do this remote storage?